# Complex Searching in CakePHP is not working

Tags: sql, cakephp, search, associations, has-many

I am in a big problem with `searching` feature, in CakePHP. Actually, I think CakePHP is not the problem here, problem is the logic. I think I don't find the perfect logic for this.

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. I have some `Models`, which are related by `hasMany` association.

Now, my search form has these fields :

```
Name, Gender, Country, Experience, Skills, Subject, Result.
```

Let's assume that all of them are textfields.

Now, what I want is, when a user search for users with these criteria, all of these criteria must be full-filled. I mean, I want the users whose `Name="Max" AND Gender="Male" AND Country="USA" AND Experience="5 Years" AND Skills="Programming" AND Subject="CSE" AND Result="4.51"`.

Here,

```
Model1:

Name, Gender, Country,.........

Model2:

Skills, Subject, Result,...........

Model3:

Exprience, .......
```

And,

```
Model1 hasMany Model2
Model1 hasMany Model3
```

So, what I tried so far is :

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
   $data=$this->request->data;
   if(!empty($data['skills']) || !empty($data['subject']) || !empty($data['result'])){
      $education=array();
      if(!empty($data['skills']))
         $education['AND']['Model2.skills']=$data['skills'];
      if(!empty($data['subject']))
         $education['AND']['Model2.subject']=$data['subject'];
      if(!empty($data['result']))
         $education['AND']['Model2.result >= ']=$data['result'];
      $bind['Model2']['conditions']=$education;
      $bind['Model2']['fields']=array('Model2.result','Model2.skills','Model2.subject');
   }
   if(!empty($data['experience'])){
      $bind['Model3']['conditions']['Model3.experience']=$data['experience'];
      $bind['Model3']['fields']=array('Model3.experience');
   }
   $personal=array();
   if(!empty($data['name']))
      $personal['AND']['Model1.name']=$data['name'];
   if(!empty($data['gender']))
      $personal['AND']['Model1.gender']=$data['gender'];
   if(!empty($data['district']))
      $personal['AND']['Model1.country']=$data['country'];
   $this->Model1->bindModel(array('hasMany'=>$bind));
   $this->paginate['Model1']['conditions']=$personal;
   $this->paginate['Model1']['fields']=array('Model1.id','Model1.name');
   $result=$this->paginate('Model1');
}
```

It gives me some data that are not related to the search, means, I want all that conditions to met, there will be no `OR`, everything will be `ANDed`.

So, what is the problem here ? What should I do ? Please help me, this is kind of emergency.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into https://github.com/CakeDC/search and save yourself 30 lines of wild code :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but that is for Cake 2.5+ I think, and it gives me an error. That's why I am trying this now.@mark

Comment: Well, it should also work with cake2.3, but you should upgrade your code to current master anyway. that is highly recommended.

Comment: Yeah, I have a plan to switch to the latest version, but for now I need a solution for this version, you know, changing version in the middle of a project is not easy. By the way, I think I got a solution, I think I should've used JOIN query for hasMany association here. I used it, and I think it gives me the result I want. Now I am just trying to get data for another complex condition.@mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I think at last I got the solution to this. I think I should've used `JOIN query for hasMany association` here.